# passport damage to e-chip

Tags: usa, passports, uk-citizens

The chip in my UK passport failed to work when I recently re-entered the UK. I have two queries about this.

1) Is there any convenient way of checking whether the chip is actually functioning correctly?

2) I wish to travel to the US soon. If the chip is not working, is it essential to get a new passport in order to be admitted to the US? Apart from the matter of the chip, my passport is not damaged visibly in any way.

Comment: Failed to work at the e-passport gate, or the immigration officer commented when admitting you that the chip wasn't working? (They're quite different)

Answer (score 7):

If you have an NFC-capable phone, you can get an app which scans a passport's chip. I've tested it successfully on my New Zealand passport. Even if the data is encrypted, at least you'll know it's scanning correctly.

Android example: [NPC Passport Reader](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=nl.novay.nfcpassportreader&hl=en)

Comment: This only answers half the question.